# Download large files from a shared sharepoint in linux

Tags: download, server

I have two sharepoint urls which were shared with me. The folders are big(>100GB). I've tried downloading them to my desktop, but it fails in few minutes everytime. I need to download them to my cloud servers for processing. Is there a way to download them to server? Please, I need the solution urgently.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint, everything is stored on a database (`content database`). Files are not stored in a file share for example, so there is no way to download files directly, without an HTTP request.

You can try to use [SharePoint REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-files-by-using-rest) to download the file:

```
http://your-web-app/sites/your-site/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/your-site/your-large-file.pdf')/$value
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more? This would be my first code in csharp.

Comment: Who talks about C#? It's just an URL to open in your browser!

Comment: I need a way to download it on a server without browser.

Comment: Yes, you can do an HTTP request without a web browser, with PowerShell or C# if you feel more confortable with it. You have to manage the authentication (default credential, token, etc.) depending the version of SharePoint (on-premise, online) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/118732/sharepoint-on-premise-authentication